# Is there an equivalent of the file-browser applet for unity?

Tags: unity, navigation

I really, really miss the file-browser-applet that was available in the gnome panel -- is there an equivalent for unity?

Answer (score 1):

I've started using the Screenlets program (available in the Ubuntu Software Center) to replace the applet items I used to run in gnome-panel (i.e. weather indicator).

Screenlets has a file browser applet.

I know that this isn't exactly *equivalent*, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

No, AFAIK, this applet has not been ported (and it would be rather difficult).